# Do MacBook Pro 2011/2012 use PC Battery for CMOS/BIOS? If yes what model?

Tags: macbook-pro, power

Normally a PC Desktop has in the mobo a small PC battery to bring energy to the CMOS/BIOS

- For [Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.3 13" Early 2011 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html)
- For [Apple MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.9 13" Mid-2012 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html)

Is not clear if these models use or not that kind of battery, if yes, what is the specific model for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No batteries in the Mac Portables you mention. Just capacitors and the main battery.

- https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/58763-what-to-do-when-your-date-and-time-are-incorrect/